# how to run several python programs from ubuntu console?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I would like to run several python programs from a ubuntu console ..
I am using PuTTY ... to open the terminal from the server ..
I currently use npm to run the javaScripts programs. I would like to know how I can run python programs in ubuntu, and close the assignment while the program is still running.

I wish I could leave the python program running, even if I close the terminal

Answer (score 1):

You need a terminal multiplexer like [screen](https://ss64.com/bash/screen.html).

With:

```
screen -S mysession
```

you can start a session and launch your programs.
You can detach that session by pressing `Ctrl+A` followed by `D`. 
You can get this session again with:

```
screen -r mysession
```